# How do I fix this Case Statement to check current and future year without getting an error?

Tags: sql-server, case-statement, dateadd, getdate, datepart

I need to check a date field to determine if it is in the current fiscal year e.g. 2019, or in the next fiscal year, e.g. 2020, depending on if the month is between January and July.  If the month is <= 7, the current year should be assigned, but if the month is > 7, then the next year is to be assigned.

Using a staging table, the SQL I tried is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM StagingTable
WHERE StagingTable.FY = 
    CASE WHEN MONTH (GETDATE()) <= 7 
         THEN YEAR (GETDATE())
    ELSE DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YY, 1, GETDATE()))
```

I also tried using a the following simple code to determine my error, but just couldn't figure out why I am getting the error.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN MONTH (GETDATE()) <= 7 
    THEN YEAR (GETDATE())
    ELSE DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YY, 1, GETDATE()))
```

I am expecting to get either 2019 or 2020 assigned to the StagingTable.FY column.  The code looks fairly simple, but I just can't get it to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: add `END` to the end of the text of your query.

Comment: Use a calendar table to check a date's properties. It takes a while to generate the table but will save you lots of time on the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `END` for `CASE`

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN MONTH (GETDATE()) <= 7 
     THEN YEAR (GETDATE())
     ELSE YEAR (GETDATE()) + 1
END;
```

Comment: Why thank you.  I kept looking at it and wondering why it was not working.  I just added END, and it worked perfectly.  Two or more heads are better than one.  Thanks  a mil.

Comment: Remember mark the answer with the green tick is solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement needs an 'end' keyword.  But also ...

`Year(date)` outputs an integer.  So consider:

```
select    * 
from      StagingTable
where     StagingTable.FY = 
             case 
             when month(getdate()) <= 7 then year(getdate())
             else year(getdate()) + 1
             end
```

or, if your version supports `iif`:

```
select    * 
from      StagingTable
where     StagingTable.FY = year(getdate()) + iif(month(getdate()) <= 7, 0, 1)
```

or, as @EzLo points out in the comments, you could create a calendar table:

```
create table dates (
    day date primary key not null,
    fiscalYear int not null
);
go

-- schedule this to run daily
create procedure dates_populate as
    insert dates (day, fiscalYear) values (
        getdate(),
        year(getdate()) + iif(month(getdate()) <= 7, 0, 1)
    );
go

select    st.*
from      StagingTable st
join      dates d on st.fy = d.fiscalYear and d.day = getdate()
```

This approach is harder to set up, but it has the benefit of being more efficient, avoiding case statements when writing code, and allowing you to hold so many more date related properties that would probably benefit you in other queries.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their responses.  Well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `YEAR(GETDATE())` 0 or 1 depending on the month:

```
SELECT * FROM StagingTable
WHERE StagingTable.FY = YEAR(GETDATE()) + 
    CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) <= 7 
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END
```